# Fetching caller location (city/country) from historical Twilio call logs

Tags: twilio

I currently receive data from each call to a Twilio number that contains info like this:

```
{
  "Called": "+xxxxxxxx",
  "ToState": "CA",
  "CallerCountry": "US",
  "Direction": "inbound",
  "Timestamp": "Sat, 25 Aug 2018 00:01:46 +0000",
  "CallbackSource": "call-progress-events",
  "CallerState": "CA",
  "ToZip": "92111",
  "SequenceNumber": "0",
  "To": "+1xxxxxx",
  "CallSid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "ToCountry": "US",
  "CallerZip": "92117",
  "CalledZip": "92111",
  "ApiVersion": "2010-04-01",
  "CallStatus": "completed",
  "CalledCity": "SAN DIEGO",
  "Duration": "1",
  "From": "+1xxxxxxxxxx",
  "CallDuration": "10",
  "AccountSid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "CalledCountry": "US",
  "CallerCity": "POWAY",
  "ToCity": "SAN DIEGO",
  "FromCountry": "US",
  "Caller": "+1xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "FromCity": "POWAY",
  "CalledState": "CA",
  "FromZip": "92117",
  "FromState": "CA",
}
```

This is provided at the end of each call to my server. However I need to fetch historical data to reconcile some missing info so I attempted to use the call log api as:

```
  const calls = await twilio.calls.list()
```

This returns a different type of structure:

```
CallInstance {
  accountSid: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  annotation: null,
  answeredBy: null,
  apiVersion: '2010-04-01',
  callerName: null,
  dateCreated: 2018-08-29T17:20:51.000Z,
  dateUpdated: 2018-08-29T17:21:52.000Z,
  direction: 'inbound',
  duration: '61',
  endTime: 2018-08-29T17:21:52.000Z,
  forwardedFrom: '+xxxxxxxxxx',
  from: '+xxxxxxxxxx',
  fromFormatted: 'xxxxxxxxxx,
  groupSid: null,
  parentCallSid: null,
  phoneNumberSid: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  price: -0.017,
  priceUnit: 'USD',
  sid: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  startTime: 2018-08-29T17:20:51.000Z,
  status: 'completed',
  subresourceUris:
   { notifications:
      '/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxx/Calls/xxxxxxxxxx/Notifications.json',
     recordings:
      '/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxx/Calls/xxxxxxxxxx/Recordings.json' },
  to: '+17603137608',
  toFormatted: '(760) 313-7608',
  uri:
   '/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxx/Calls/xxxxxxxxxx.json'
}
```

However this has no caller location data such as the city/country. Is there another API call to get the location data or am I left to my own devices by analyzing the phone number?

Answer (score 0):

So after diving into it it doesn't appear to be possible. I ended up using something like the Google phone lib to analyze the number and return country.